# splitting a string if a substring has occured

Tags: python, string, split

how can I say if a string hit https (with no space) split it into two words? 
For example in `Join us!https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom` want to make it like `Join us!` and `https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way if you are only going to split on the `https` keyword

```
myString = 'Join us!https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom'

(head, sep, tail) = myString.partition('https')

print head  #Prints Join us!
print sep + tail #Prints the rest
```

Answer (score 6):

Read abount [index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index)

```
s = 'Join us!https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom'
[s[0:s.index('https')], s[s.index('https'):]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the `https` with the `index` method.

```
s = 'Join us!https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom'
idx = s.index('https')
parts = [s[0:idx], s[idx:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

no solutions is complete without regexes!

```
import re

s = 'join us!https://t.co/Fe0oTahdom'
tokens = re.split('(https)', s)
print tokens[0]
print tokens[1] + tokens[2]
```

Comment: There is a flaw with this answer if the url happens to contain "https", eg `s = 'join us!https://t.co/Fehttpsom'`. This type of bug is one of the most frustrating to track down.

Answer (score 1):

Split and join, if https is in string.

```
string = "Join us!https://t.co/Fehttpsom"
if "https://" in string:
    print " https://".join(string.split("https://", 1))
```

Join us! https://t.co/Fehttpsom and make sure you do not split just on the first occurrence of https as in "Visit our website with https now ;)"

Comment: This has the same problem as @MK.'s answer. You can pass `1` to the maxsplit argument though.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy you are right and I learned something - winwin ;)